# How stop text to speech in Base adapter

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I have a custom `ListView` with `BaseAdapter`. In this custom `ListView` when a user clicks on any particular text, it speaks the text but the problem is that when any user clicks on the back button how to stop this text from the `BaseAdapter`. I know how to stop from an `Activity` but don't know how to stop from `BaseAdapter` when the user presses back button. Here is my code:

```
package bible.swordof.God;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;
import petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker.ColorPicker;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class BaseAdopter extends BaseAdapter implements  TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
    public BaseAdopter(Context context, List<String> versenumber, List<String> verseid, List<String> verselist, List<String> refernce) {
        this.context = context;
        this.versenumber = versenumber;
        this.verseid = verseid;
        this.verselist = verselist;
        this.refernce = refernce;
    }

ALLVERSE allverse;
    ArrayList<String> colors;
    private Context context;
    private List<String> versenumber;
    private List<String>verseid;
    private List<String> verselist;
    private List<String> refernce;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return versenumber.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.versedisplayrow,parent,false);



        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(context, this);



        final TextView verseno;
     final TextView verselistview;
     ImageView share;
     ToggleButton addfavoruite;
     ImageView speakverse;
final  LinearLayout linearLayout;
     verseno=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.versenumber);
      verseno.setText(versenumber.get(position));
      verselistview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.verse);
      verselistview.setText(verselist.get(position));
      addfavoruite=(ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.adbookmark);
     linearLayout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
     share=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.share);
     speakverse=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.speak);

if(DefaultSettings.nightmode(context)){

    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#363437"));

    verselistview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    verseno.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
}
speakverse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        singleverse(verselist.get(position).toString());

    }
});




int a=position+1;
        colors=new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add("#e0e0eb");
        colors.add("#ccffff");
        colors.add("#ffe6ff");
        colors.add("#ffffcc");
        colors.add("#ccffcc");
        colors.add("#e6f2ff");

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("DATA",MODE_PRIVATE);


        int getverse=sharedPreferences.getInt("versenumber",1);



        if(a==getverse){
            if(DefaultSettings.highlight(context)){
                DefaultSettings.color(context);

                linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(DefaultSettings.colorpicked);
            }


        }



        if(Checkisfavourite("favourite","id",verseid.get(position)))
        {
            if(verseid.get(position).equals(verseid.get(position))){

             addfavoruite.setChecked(true);

            }else {

                addfavoruite.setChecked(false);
            }
        }



        addfavoruite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("id",verseid.get(position));
            contentValues.put("bookname",refernce.get(position));
            contentValues.put("versenumber",versenumber.get(position));
            contentValues.put("verse",verselist.get(position));
            long check=mDb.insert("favourite",null,contentValues);
            Toasty.success(context, "Added in favouite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        }
        else {
            mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            long delete= mDb.delete("favourite","id=?",new String[]{verseid.get(position)});
            Toasty.error(context, "Remove in favouite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        }
    }
});
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toasty.info(context, "Sharing a verse.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, refernce.get(position) + ":" + versenumber.get(position) + '\n'   + verselist.get(position) +


                        +'\n' +'\n' +'\n' +"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bible.swordof.God");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                context.startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });






  /*    linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                //Toasty.success(activity, "PICK COLOR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibe.vibrate(100);


                mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("verseid",colors.get(position));
                final long check=mDb.insert("highlight",null,contentValues);


                //id get




                //postion
                //Toast.makeText(activity, ""+getItemId(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(context);


                colorPicker.setColors(colors).setColumns(4).setTitle("HIGHLIGHT VERSE").setRoundColorButton(true).setOnChooseColorListener(new ColorPicker.OnChooseColorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChooseColor(int position, int color) {


                       linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors.get(position)));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }
                }).show();






                return false;
            }
        });
*/






     return view;



    }

    public boolean Checkisfavourite(String TableName,  String dbfield, String fieldValue) {

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + " = " + fieldValue;
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();

            // Toast.makeText(activity, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }else {

            // Toast.makeText(activity, "TRUE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        cursor.close();


        return true;
    }

    public boolean colorcheck(String TableName,  String dbfield, String fieldValue) {

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + " = " + fieldValue;
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();

            // Toast.makeText(activity, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }else {

            // Toast.makeText(activity, "TRUE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        cursor.close();


        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

            // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
            } else {

            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
        }

    }
    private void singleverse(String text) {
        DefaultSettings.speed(context);
        textToSpeech.setPitch(DefaultSettings.pitchvalue);
        textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(DefaultSettings.speedvalue);
        textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

public  void  stop(){
        if (textToSpeech != null) {
        textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your TextToSpeech object belongs to your BaseAdapter when it should belong to the parent activity.

Instead of housing it in the adapter and calling speak on it every time the user clicks an item, I would instead house it in the parent activity and use an "interface callback" that sends a message to the parent when the user clicks an item, sending back the string to speak.  This callback relationship works the exact same way as the TextToSpeech.OnInitListener callback that you're already using.

Once the TTS belongs to the parent activity, you can use the activity lifecycle functions to control the shutdown of the TTS like normal.

If you study and understand the following, you should be able to merge it into your code and get a working solution:

Make these changes to your custom BaseAdapter:

```
// Remove the TextToSpeech object from this class.

public class MyBaseAdapter {

// add this interface definition to your adapter
public interface SpeechClickSubscriber {
    void stringNeedsToBeSpoken(String verse);
}

// add this property (the subscriber)
private SpeechClickSubscriber speechClickSubscriber;

// *add* this functionality to your adapter's existing constructor
MyBaseAdapter(SpeechClickSubscriber parent) {
    speechClickSubscriber = parent;
}

//...

// change this section of code in your getView() method
speakverse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){

    // change this...
    // singleverse(verselist.get(position).toString());

    // to this:
    speechClickSubscriber.stringNeedsToBeSpoken(verselist.get(position).toString());

}
});

// ...


}
```

Make these changes to your MainActivity (*or whatever your parent activity is*):

```
// add the SpeechClickSubscriber implementation
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  MyBaseAdapter.SpeechClickSubscriber, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

MyBaseAdapter adapter;
TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // using app context is better and less error prone.
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);


}

// *add* this method to this activity (this is the answer to your question)
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopTTS();
}

// use this method as your "onStart()" method...
// this will help prevent any user input processing until the tts is initialized.
private void start_Activity_Because_TTS_Has_Initialized() {

    adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(this);

}


// *MOVE* this method from your base adapter to this (parent) activity:
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

        // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        } else {

        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }

}

// *move* and *rename* this method from your adapter to the parent activity:
// from:

/*
private void singleverse(String text) {
    DefaultSettings.speed(context);
    textToSpeech.setPitch(DefaultSettings.pitchvalue);
    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(DefaultSettings.speedvalue);
    textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
} */

// to:

@Override
public void stringNeedsToBeSpoken(String verse) {

    Log.i("XXX","stringNeedsToBeSpoken() was called because the user clicked an item.");
    Log.i("XXX","This method is being called because this activity subscribes to the callback we created and added to our base adapter.");

    //DefaultSettings.speed(context);  // <----------------- I don't know what this does.
    // I'm assuming that DefaultSettings is a static class you have made.
    textToSpeech.setPitch(DefaultSettings.pitchvalue);
    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(DefaultSettings.speedvalue);
    textToSpeech.speak(verse, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}



public  void  stopTTS(){
    if (textToSpeech != null) {
        textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();

    }
}


}
```